# How to I keep my app from crashing when, as far as I can tell, the suggested fixes regarding unconnected outlets aren't working for me?

Tags: ios, swift

I'm trying to request permission to get someones location but the app crashes because of a connection I have.

Other people have suggested to check any outlets that aren't connected. I only have one and I have deleted it and reconnected it multiple times. I don't believe that is the problem but I may be missing something. I think the problem is something else to do with the fact that I was following an old tutorial.

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<UIViewController 0x7feb27510490> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key mainMapView.'

This is my code:

```
func checkLocationAuthorization() {
    switch CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus() {
    case .authorizedWhenInUse:
        //do map stuff
        break
    case .denied:
        // show alert to turn on permissions
        break
    case .notDetermined:
        // havent picked yet
        locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
    case .restricted:
        //show alert
        break
    case .authorizedAlways:
        break
    }
}
```

I'm also getting an alert on the switch; saying it may have additional unknown values. that might be the issue

Comment: "Other people have suggested to check any outlets that aren't connected. I only have one and I have deleted it and reconnected it multiple times" The class of the `UIViewController` in your Storyboard is `UIViewController` (default one) and not the custom one you use. It could be because you didn't set it, or a case to check in Modules/Targets.

Comment: Add your xib or Storyboard screen

Answer (score 0):

You report that you are receiving an exception:

> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<UIViewController 0x7feb27510490> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key mainMapView.'

The presence of `UIViewController` in that exception is telling you that this base class doesn’t have that outlet. Note it’s not referencing your class, but rather `UIViewController`. That suggests that you neglected to set the base class for your scene in the storyboard.

---

If your question is about this code in Swift 5, you will receive a compile-time warning and you can tap on that alert and then on its “fix” button, it will add the necessary clause (I’ve replaced the default `fatalError()` with `break`):

```
 func checkLocationAuthorization() {
    switch CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus() {
    case .authorizedWhenInUse:
        //do map stuff
        break

    case .denied:
        // show alert to turn on permissions
        break

    case .notDetermined:
        // havent picked yet
        locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()

    case .restricted:
        //show alert
        break

    case .authorizedAlways:
        break

    @unknown default:
        break
    }
}
```

The idea in Swift 5 is that we should also add a `@unknown` clause for any cases that might be added in future iOS versions in order to future-proof our code. (If you already have a `default` clause, though, this is not needed; only when you’ve enumerated all of the clauses do you need to add this `@unknown` case.) See [SE-0192: Handling Future Enum Cases](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0192-non-exhaustive-enums.md#unknown).

Comment: When I click on the view controller in the storyboard and look at the identity inspector, it says my class is called "ViewController". Does that mean I need to change it to "UIViewController"? I don't understand

Comment: If your exception is saying “'[<UIViewController 0x...> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key mainMapView.'”, (with `UIViewController`, not `ViewController` or whatever) then that means that it has instantiated a `UIViewController`, not your subclass. The typical source of that problem is the failure to specify one’s base class correctly. But it sounds like you have set it to `ViewController`, so it’s not immediately obvious why you’re having that problem. I’d suggest creating a new blank project and seeing if you can reproduce the problem there.

Answer (score -1):

Check your IBOutlet from storyboard.
Probably smth wrong with your `mainMapView`.